# Show custom fileds based on other custom field value on CREATE ISSUE screen

Tags: jira, custom-fields, jira-plugin

I'm implementing a help desk in JIRA where I have two drop downs - both '**single value select**' for **Category** and **Sub-category**.

For example,
I have following **Categories**:

- Content Development
- Events
- Design

And each category has a list of **sub-categories** within them. For example, **Design** will have following list of options

- Event Collateral
- Branding
- Business Cards

By default, ONLY **Category** dropdown should be displayed on the **CREATE ISSUE** screen.
When user selects one of the **categories**, corresponding **sub-category** drop-down should be displayed on the CREATE ISSUE screen **AND** that sub-category dropdown should be MANDATORY field.

I looked up for possible solution at the following links:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA052/Displaying+a+Field+Based+on+Another+Field+Selection
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Displaying+a+Field+Based+on+Another+Field+Selection
- https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/217176/show-hide-custom-field-depend-on-another-custom-field-value

The first two links basically suggests the same solution - that is to put a JAVASCRIPT in the description field of the custom field and the same is suggested on many other blogs on this issue. They all give this very same example.

However this is not working for me. When I put any JAVASCRIPT in the description of the custom-field, it runs immediately upon saving - on the **Field Configuration** screen. For example, I just put a following JAVASCRIPT in the description and I got the alert right away (on the **Field Configuration** screen).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('hi');
 </script>
```

However, I do not get any alert on the CREATE ISSUE screen. So, not sure if I am missing anything here. Please advise if I'm looking in the right direction.

The 3rd link, suggests to create a plugin from the JIRA machine. However, I do not have access to that machine, I just have admin access to JIRA.

Is there any feasible way to achieve it via default JIRA configurations/external plugins which are ready-to-use?

My JIRA version is: 6.1.4

Comment: I think I'd ask again at answers.atlassian.com

Answer (score 0):

I have used Java script in custom fields in JIRA 6.0.8,JIRA 6.2.4 and JIRA 6.4.8 as well, so I think it should definitely work in JIRA 6.1.4.

You only need to put java script in sub category custom field as below:

For example for Design ->
Replace customfield_ID1 with custom id of Category Custom field and  customfield_ID2 with custom id of Sub Category Design Custom field

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
JIRA.bind(JIRA.Events.NEW_CONTENT_ADDED, function (e, context) {
callChangeFunction();
});
callChangeFunction();
function callChangeFunction(){
showHidField();
// dropdown custom field change function
$("#customfield_ID1").change(function() {
showHidField();
});

}

function showHidField(){
//drop down field selected value
var dropDownFieldval =$.trim($("#customfield_ID1 :selected").text());
//test field1
$("#customfield_ID2").closest('div.field-group').hide();
if(dropDownFieldval == 'Design'){
$("#customfield_ID2").closest('div.field-group').show();
}else
$("#customfield_ID2").closest('div.field-group').hide();

}

});

</script>
```

Above will show or hide the field, please ensure that Category and Subcategory custom fields both are on same screen (Ex: Create Screen)

Now in order to make them Mandatory, you need to write that code as validator on create transition in Project Workflow as below:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.option.LazyLoadedOption;
LazyLoadedOption selOption = issue.getCustomFieldValue   (customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject('customfield_ID1'));
(selOption.getValue()=='Design' && cfValues[Name of design Sub Category field#'])|| selOption.getValue()=='Events';
```

Make sure that you have Behaviour Plugin installed to get simple script validator

Hope this helps!

Priyanka Lavania